# Potential (vague) answer to a question: should I post it?

Tags: discussion, support

The question is:

math.stackexchange.com/questions/501660/is-there-a-way-to-get-trig-functions-without-a-calculator

This following answer is quite vauge and I do not think I can develop it further alone, but it may it be of some help, should I post it as an answer?

> Where $A$ and $B$ are vectors, and $x$ is $A ∠ B$.
>
> $A · B = |A| |B| cos(x)$
>
> This uses trigonometry, however the following definition achieves the same result without using trigonometry:
>
> [image: Here]

Comment: Sorry for the broken formatting, I'm fixing it now.

Comment: You are not reallly answering the question, no? Given an angle $x$, how do you know which $A, B$ to use?

Comment: I think you are correct @Arctic Char. I am able to show an equation, the interesting part being the formula on the right hand side of the equals, that seems to unavoidable require trigonomic functions. Followed by an equation, again the interesting part being on the right of the equals, achieving the same goal without trigonometry.